# MySQL variant of Oracle (+) sign for outer join?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, outer-join, database-migration

can someone help me re-write this SQL for MySQL database (has both subquery and outer join)

```
**select REPORT_PACKAGE.SUBJECT_LINE, ACTIVATION_DT, PARAM_VALUE, REPORT_URL, hasCustomerDetails,
isAccountsRolledUp FROM REPORT_PACKAGE, REPORT_PARAMETER, REPORT_DEFINITION, REPORT_PACKAGE_CONTENT,
(select param_value as hasCustomerDetails, rpt_package_id from report_parameter
where param_name = 'hasCustomerDetails') a,
(select param_value isAccountsRolledUp, rpt_package_id rid from report_parameter
where param_name = 'isAccountsRolledUp') as b
WHERE REPORT_PACKAGE.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = REPORT_PARAMETER.RPT_PACKAGE_ID
and param_name = 'rulePlanId' and
REPORT_PACKAGE_CONTENT.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = REPORT_PACKAGE.RPT_PACKAGE_ID and
REPORT_PACKAGE_CONTENT.RPT_DEF_ID = REPORT_DEFINITION.RPT_DEF_ID AND
REPORT_URL like '%AcctNbr%' and REPORT_PACKAGE.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = a.RPT_PACKAGE_ID(+)
and REPORT_PACKAGE.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = b.RPT_PACKAGE_ID(+);**
```

I tried the following and it didnt work :

```
**select repa.SUBJECT_LINE, ACTIVATION_DT, PARAM_VALUE, REPORT_URL, hasCustomerDetails,
isAccountsRolledUp FROM REPORT_PACKAGE repa
left join (select param_value as hasCustomerDetails, rpt_package_id from report_parameter
where param_name = 'hasCustomerDetails') as a
left join (select param_value as isAccountsRolledUp, rpt_package_id from report_parameter
where param_name = 'isAccountsRolledUp') as b
left join a on repa.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = a.RPT_PACKAGE_ID
left join b on repa.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = b.RPT_PACKAGE_ID
inner join REPORT_PACKAGE_CONTENT repc on repa.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = repc.RPT_PACKAGE_ID
inner join REPORT_DEFINITION rd on repc.RPT_DEF_ID = rd.RPT_DEF_ID
where REPORT_URL like '%AcctNbr%'**
```

Comment: -1 Make a minimal example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: You're trying to join `a` and `b` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to rewrite the query, and this is what I have -

```
SELECT
  REPORT_PACKAGE.SUBJECT_LINE,
  ACTIVATION_DT,
  PARAM_VALUE,
  REPORT_URL,
  hasCustomerDetails,
  isAccountsRolledUp
FROM REPORT_PACKAGE
  JOIN REPORT_PARAMETER
    ON REPORT_PARAMETER.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = REPORT_PACKAGE.RPT_PACKAGE_ID
  JOIN REPORT_PACKAGE_CONTENT
    ON REPORT_PACKAGE_CONTENT.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = REPORT_PACKAGE.RPT_PACKAGE_ID
  JOIN REPORT_DEFINITION
    ON REPORT_DEFINITION.RPT_DEF_ID = REPORT_PACKAGE_CONTENT.RPT_DEF_ID
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT param_value hasCustomerDetails, rpt_package_id FROM report_parameter WHERE param_name = 'hasCustomerDetails') a
    ON a.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = REPORT_PACKAGE.RPT_PACKAGE_ID
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT param_value isAccountsRolledUp, rpt_package_id rid FROM report_parameter WHERE param_name = 'isAccountsRolledUp') b
    ON b.RPT_PACKAGE_ID = REPORT_PACKAGE.RPT_PACKAGE_ID
WHERE
  param_name = 'rulePlanId'
  AND REPORT_URL like '%AcctNbr%'
```

Add table aliases to make this query more readable.